# C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const char [9]' to 'char*'

Tags: c++, arduino, qt5

I am working on a Qt5 project written in C++.  Building the project gives an error:

> C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const char [9]' to 'char*'

Which points to the line of code below:

```
port_name= "\\\\.\\COM4";//COM4-macine, COM4-11 Office

SerialPort arduino(port_name);
if (arduino.isConnected())
    qDebug()<< "ardunio connection established" << endl;
else
    qDebug()<< "ERROR in ardunio connection, check port name";
//the following codes are omitted ....
```

What is the problem here, and how can I correct it?

Comment: Declare `port_name` as `const char *` instead of `char *`.

Comment: After I do so, it brings a different error related to the following code Arduino(port_name), cannot covert argument 1 from 'const char *' to 'char *'. SerialPort(char *portName) has been defined elsewhere.

Comment: @jingweimo You will have to cast it back to `char*` when passing it to `SerialPort()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String literals are constant data in C++ (compilers tend to store them in read-only memory when possible).

In C++11 and later, you can no longer assign a string literal directly to a *pointer-to-non-const-char* (`char*`) <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1: though some C++11 compilers may allow it as a non-standard extension for backwards compatibility, which may need to be enabled manually via compiler flag.</sup>

So, you need to declare `port_name` as a *pointer-to-const-char* instead (`const char *` or `char const *`). But then you will have to cast it back to a non-const `char*` when passing it to `SerialPort()`:

```
const char *port_name = "\\\\.\\COM4";
SerialPort arduino(const_cast<char*>(port_name));
```

Or simply:

```
SerialPort arduino(const_cast<char*>("\\\\.\\COM4"));
```

The alternative is to declare `port_name` as a non-const `char[]` buffer, copy the string literal into it, and then pass it to `SerialPort()`:

```
char port_name[] = "\\\\.\\COM4";
SerialPort arduino(port_name);
```

Answer (score 6):

In C++, in contrast to C, string literals are `const`. So any pointer to such a string literal must be `const`, too:

```
const char* port_name = "\\\\.\\COM4";  // OK
// char* port_name = "\\\\.\\COM4";  // Not OK
```