# Unicode characters problem/converting arguments

Tags: c++

This is self-explanatory, but can't get it right.
This is my code. 
I need to use the template in order to work with multiple files, to write/read them and do operations.

```
class MOBILE
{
public:
    int id;
    string tara;
    string brand;
    string culoare;
    int an;
    virtual void fscanf_el(FILE *ptr) = 0;
public:
    friend int operator < (const MOBILE&, const MOBILE&);
    friend int operator > (const MOBILE&, const MOBILE&);
    friend int operator < (const MOBILE&, const int&);
    friend int operator > (const MOBILE&, const int&);
    friend int operator == (const MOBILE&, const int&);
};



template <typename T> class GG {

public:
    vector <T> mas; 
    int size; 

    GG(char *file_name) { 
        FILE *ptr; 
        ptr = fopen(file_name, "r"); 
        T temp;
        MOBILE t[50];
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            t[i].fscanf_el(ptr);
            mas.push_back(t[i]);
        }
        fclose(ptr); 
        size = mas.size(); 
        cout << "  " << endl;
    }

};
```

And this is my main.cpp

```
....
    int main() {

        GG <MOBILE> my_table_sort("f1.txt"); 
        GG <MOBILE> my_table_unsort("f2.txt");

        cout << "****************************************" << endl;
        menu_show(); 
    ....
```

The error i get is by this 2 lines

```
 GG <MOBILE> my_table_sort("f1.txt"); 
 GG <MOBILE> my_table_unsort("f2.txt");
```

The error is
    C2664: 'GG::GG(GG &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [7]' to 'char *'

I don't know how to make it work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In C++, generally best to use `std::string` rather than `char*`.

Comment: I did try string and getting:
cannot convert argument 1 from  'std::string *' to 'const char *'.
Im kind new to this.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of `std::string*`. Also, your title mentions Unicode, but nothing in your question is related to Unicode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const char \[9\]' to 'char\*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100488/c2440-cannot-convert-from-const-char-9-to-char). Not sure why you mention unicode.

Answer (score 0):

> cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [7]' to 'char *'

In C++, a [*string literal*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) is of type `const char[N]`, where `N` is the number of characters plus a null terminator. So, `"f1.txt"` and `"f2.txt"` are both `const char[7]`.

A `const char[]` *decays* to a `const char*` pointer to the 1st character.

You cannot pass a `pointer-to-const` where a `pointer-to-non-const` is expected (but the reverse is allowed).

Your `GG()` constructor takes a non-const `char*` pointer as input, so you cannot pass string literals to it unless you cast away their `const`-ness:

```
GG <MOBILE> my_table_sort(const_cast<char*>("f1.txt"));
GG <MOBILE> my_table_unsort(const_cast<char*>("f2.txt"));
```

The better solution is to change `GG()` to take a `const char*` instead, then you can pass both `char*` and `const char*` pointers to it. You should also do this because `fopen()` takes a `const char*` as input anyway:

```
GG(const char *file_name)
{
    FILE *ptr = fopen(file_name, "r");
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, change `GG()` to take a `std:string()` instead, which also allows `char*` and `const char*` inputs:

```
GG(const std::string &file_name)
{
    FILE *ptr = fopen(file_name.c_str(), "r");
    ...
}
```